# How to render an animation starting in the middle?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

So, i am rendering a heavy animation, and i'm halfway done. However, i stopped the rendering so i could work on another project during the day, and i plan to resume the render overnight. I just cant tell Blender to start rendering the animation in the middle. BTW this is still 2.79b. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the properties panel choose Render settings (the camera). There is an option to choose your starting frame as noted in the picture below:[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition, in the newest version as of April 2023, I think 3.5? It’s in *Output Settings*, under *Frame Range*.